# Your page did not fire its `load` event within `60000ms` only on Github Actions

Tags: cypress, sveltekit

I have Cypress tests failing only on Github CI with this error:

```
Your page did not fire its `load` event within `60000ms`.
```

I assume this is because the Cypress browser is stuck loading something Github Actions environment is blocking. Tests run fine locally. However, because I do not have access to the browser console, I cannot know what is causing the error.

Based on Cypress the service screenshot the page loaded fine, though.

How can I either

- Disable `load` event check in my Cypress tests, as I assume this is not a real issue
- Access JavaScript logs or Network tab logs though Cypress service to confirm what could be the issue in Github Actions run-time environment

[This is a SvelteKit based site](https://kit.svelte.dev/).

Comment: where you able to find a solution for this?

Comment: The solution was to switch to an alternative testing framework

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not currently possible to opt-out of waiting for the load event: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/788